Will frame that hosts Tiagra R4700 crankset be compatible with GRX FC RX-600?
Looking to upgrade and I wonder if I can just go ahead and order the new GRX crankset. Is it safe to assume that it's going to be compatible with my frame because it hosts a 2020 Tiagra 4700?

because it hosts a 2020 Tiagra 4700 Just to be certain, is the current crankset a Tiagra 4700, or something else?  Cranksets often differ from the groupset of bicycles.  For example: Cannondale CAAD Optimo 2 with Tiagra shifters and derailleurs and an FSA crankset.  It'd also be helpful to add the make and model of your frame just to be sure any answer you get doesn't cause you to buy something that doesn't fit.

@AndrewHenle the bike is exactly this:
https://archiv.cube.eu/pl/2020/329700
It was bought second-hand, but all the components were stock (and looked like only a few rides in - in perfect condition :D)

Most of the time, you can put any crankset in a frame provided that you are putting road or gravel cranks in a road frame, and MTB cranksets in MTB frames.
First, you look for a BB that a) matches your BB shell type, then b) make sure the BB supports your crank type. In your case, say you have a BSA BB shell. You also know both your current crank and the target crank have 24mm spindles. Any Shimano road or gravel crankset will fit, and you can re-use your BB. If you had wanted to, say, put a Quarq crankset and a power meter on your bike, you now need a different BB.
Of current frames, I don't know of any edge cases where a BB is outright incompatible with a frame. Trek's old BB90 standard wouldn't take 30mm spindles, but that's out of production. BB86, the Shimano press fit standard, is likely to have poorer bearing durability with 30mm spindles (including SRAM DUB). This is because, since Shimano only does 24mm spindles, they didn't design PF86 with enough room for a 30mm spindle and good bearings (they'll be a bit smaller than ideal, hence faster wear).
Another issue you need to be aware of is chainline, or the lateral distance between the chainrings and the bike's centerline. Shimano's GRX groups have a chainline 2.5mm further to the right than the road groups. SRAM does the same with its wide cranks. As a result, Shimano doesn't officially state that road front derailleurs are compatible with GRX, because the road FDs were designed with the road chainlines in mind. I believe I've heard people say that a road FD worked for them, but there may have been one or two people reporting the opposite. It's likely that you will be OK, because of course they have to make the FD able to handle a range of situations to account for variations in seat tube widths. You could buy a GRX FD, and return it if it isn't needed.
While this wasn't asked in the question, I've written before that I think manufacturers should offer more sub-compact crank options. I infer from the OP's question that they are doing this because they want lower gears, which supports my hypothesis. In Shimano's case, you can argue that GRX is that option - but what if I want to equip a road bike with sub-compact and I would prefer a more tightly-spaced cassette, or I'd prefer not to have a clutch on the RD, etc.
Similar to Shimano, SRAM's wide crank option has a wider chainline and needs a different FD if you use a 2x. Campagnolo has one sub-compact option with 12s Chorus, and that's only 48/32, which is equivalent to about one cog difference. And that's the only option on their road groups.
